# Novel where sick children are transported to a world with three types of machines controlled by the villain

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult, childrens-novel

I strongly remember reading this book, including large chunks of the plot and setting, except that I can't remember the author or the title. After fruitlessly wrestling with various book searching tools, and asking this question on another story identification forum, I've come here.

I forget if this was YA or a children's book, but it was definitely a novel. I read this in Canada from the public library, probably 10+ years ago by now.

I read it in English, which I think was the original language. I don't remember the cover very much at all, but I think it was probably some combination of grey, browns and black. It might have had gears or other machine elements on the cover, also. If I had to describe the overall look it would be "grimy".

In this setting, very sick children are transported to another world, although no one in the main world(which is identical to ours) seems to know this, so it might just be the child's mind that crosses over. This happens to the main character(I don't think he's older then 13 or so) while he's walking with his family(maybe including a sister?). It's really hot out when this happens, and the transportation involves the heat haze on the pavement somehow, I think.

Once they're in the other world, the children need to make their way to a special city in order to get home and recover from their illness. If they die in the other world, then they succumb to the illness and die in real life. To help in this, each child has a guide, an adult native to the other world(it's unclear where the guides ultimately come from, at least in my memory) that brings them to the city.

However, relatively recently, this has changed. The villain has walled off the city, and guards it with hordes of machines to prevent the children from making it home(I forget his exact motivation for this. Maybe he enslaves them to build more machines?). There are three types of machines: there are ones with a rotating light on top powerful enough to blind you if you see it, and Scrapers, which are like big cranes that scrape off people trying to climb the wall. I forget what the third type of machine was, but if I had to guess I'd say they have flamethrowers.

The main character's guide is an old man nicknamed 'Spider', who was blinded by the first type of machine, but is very experienced and claims to know a secret way into the city. He has a walking stick that's covered in grubby bandages(I forget what's under the bandages). Very very fuzzy on this, but I *think* it's later revealed that Spider was the one who designed the machines in the first place, and the villain blinded him with his own creations to ensure that he wouldn't be able to oppose him. As a sort of atonement for accidentally ruining everything, Spider became a guide for the children and has actually managed to smuggle a few of them into the city.

I don't remember most of the rest of the story, but I do remember that near the end the main character ends up in the villain's mansion as a 'guest'. The villain tries to bribe the main character to his side with various luxuries, before finally setting out to conquer the rest of the other world with his enormous army of machines(Consisting of 100-1000 of each type). He displays the machines one type at a time, and gloats about how maybe he'd like to "rule a nation of the blind" when he brings out the legion of spinny-light machines. He brings the main character with him in his car doing this, which is a big mistake. While the villain's distracted with something, the main character grabs the remote controls for the machines and sends them all backwards as fast as he can, destroying the machine army(I think they fall off a cliff?) and that breaks the villain's power. Then, I think after an interval of peacefully living in the city, the main character returns to the normal world and his family, recovered from his illness and secure in the knowledge that with the wall destroyed and machines dismantled any future sick children will have much better odds of making it back.